# Is there a lite wallet for Bitcoin Cash

Tags: bitcoin-cash

Free money, is free money.  Last week I transferred my distributed BTC funds to a BTC lite wallet so that I could be holding funds before the Bitcoin Cash fork.

I now have some BCC sitting in a BCC account, but I need to move it to an exchange.  I've searched and searched, but I can't find a simple, straightforward answer.

Is there a lite wallet or a (moderately) safe web wallet that will allow me to import my keys and withdraw my funds?

Also, I'm well aware of security risks with web wallets.  I've already deposited all of my funds back to their respective exchanges and the BTC account is empty, and I plan on never using it again.  Now, all I want to do is access my Bitcoin Cash funds as painlessly and quickly as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.electroncash.org/

But you may have problem to setup this wallet if you use non-english windows 10 version. For example with cyrillic letters

Answer (score 0):

How about the local wallet Coinomi running on Android which supports Bitcoin Cash and others?

You can also run Coinomi in the Android emulator Bluestack on your Windows PC.

Comment: I use a Mac and Bluestack has never properly worked for me.

Comment: What about Droid4X or Andy OS based on Virtual Box?

Comment: I've not tried Droid4X but AndyOS hasn't worked either.  I don't know why, but I've always had the worst of luck with Android emulation.

Comment: OK, buy a cheap Android phone ;) Or use a wallet for iOS. Coinomi should be there soon.